# How to listen from RTMP url in Dart / Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, file, request, rtmp

We have an RTMP server that streams from a camera, and that stream URL is sent to the Flutter app to be displayed we archive this using the package: `media_kit` which is working perfectly.

We now need to implement a feature where the Flutter app records X amount of seconds when a button is pressed.

My question is can I create an HTTP-like request listen to the stream bytes and write an mp4 file?

I have tried this:
been `widget.url` = = rtmp://rtmp-server-the-rest-of-the-url

```
    var uri = Uri.parse(widget.url);
    try {
      final path = await _localPath;
      final file = await File('$path/test.mp4').create(recursive: true);
      var request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);
      final response = await request.send();
      var bytes = <int>[];
      response.stream.listen((newBytes) {
        bytes.addAll(newBytes);
      });
      Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 10), (() {
        file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
      }));
    } catch (error) {
      print(error.toString());
    }
```

without success i got an error:
`Invalid argument(s): Unsupported scheme 'rtmp' in URI rtmp://rtmp-server-rest-of-the-url`

Answer (score 0):

the http package doesn't work for RTMP links hence the invalid url error you get try [rtmp_broadcaster: ^2.2.4](https://pub.dev/packages/rtmp_broadcaster)